# Android: How to create EditText field at the bottom of PopupMenu?

Tags: android, xml, menu

I have a PopupMenu view in my code and I want an EditText view to be one of it's options so a user can create a new file from the same menu where they select existing files. According to this post : *[Android : Display an EditText in a menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699073/android-display-an-edittext-in-a-menu)*
it is not possible to use an EditText view as a PopupMenu item.

My question is, is there a workaround to not being able to declare an EditText as a menu item? Perhaps, creating a ListView and declaring the Popupmenu and EditText views as children?

Below is code I tried but produced, as predicted, a Popupmenu with no visible EditText Field.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <item android:id="@+id/new_track"
        android:title="+ create new track"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend" />

</menu>
```

The code I'm suggesting would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <item android:id="@+id/new_track"
        android:title="+ create new track"/>
</menu>
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend" />

</ListView>
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to create `RelativeLayout` and then set where each element need to go in queue.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <item android:id="@+id/new_track"
              android:title="+ create new track"/>

    <RelativeLayout>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/> //this line put edittext at bottom
    </RelativeLayout>
</menu>
```

**EDIT:** After many searches of this specific problem I can only say: no, you can't do that. You can only create a menu `item` which would call a specific fragment or it would change your toolbar to SearchView (like hide `TextView`, show EditText and `Button`s).

For the first option take a look at: [Search item on action bar android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180109/search-item-on-action-bar-android)

For the second option: http://blog.rhesoft.com/2015/03/30/tutorial-android-actionbar-with-material-design-and-search-field/

Comment: I tried this but the EditText widget is still not showing up

Comment: My app runs in fullscreen mode so there's no app bar. I used a workaround for my problem where clicking on an option to create a new file in my popup menu changes the visibility of a separate EditText field where the user can name the file.

Comment: I'll give you the correct answer rep anyways for responding. Thanks